# sinatra app crashes on heroku - failed to load command thin

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app that works fine locally, but when I push it to heroku I get this :

```
2020-12-28T11:11:23.206376+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -p 55504`
2020-12-28T11:11:25.994322+00:00 app[web.1]: Doing `require 'backports'` is deprecated and will not load any backport in the next major release.
2020-12-28T11:11:25.994336+00:00 app[web.1]: Require just the needed backports instead, or 'backports/latest'.
2020-12-28T11:11:26.249566+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: thin (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/thin)
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257657+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionSpecification
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257658+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sinatra-activerecord-2.0.21/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb:25:in `registered'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257659+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1400:in `block in register'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257659+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1398:in `each'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257659+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1398:in `register'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257660+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1969:in `register'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257660+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:2030:in `register'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257661+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sinatra-activerecord-2.0.21/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb:81:in `<module:Sinatra>'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257661+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sinatra-activerecord-2.0.21/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257662+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:88:in `require'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257662+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:88:in `rescue in block in require'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257662+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `block in require'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257663+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `each'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257663+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `require'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257664+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257664+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257665+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config.ru:1:in `require_relative'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257665+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config.ru:1:in `block in <main>'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257665+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257666+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257666+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257667+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257667+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thin-1.8.0/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257667+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thin-1.8.0/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257668+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thin-1.8.0/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:42:in `for'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257668+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thin-1.8.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:170:in `load_adapter'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257668+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thin-1.8.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:74:in `start'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257669+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thin-1.8.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:203:in `run_command'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257669+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thin-1.8.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:159:in `run!'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257670+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thin-1.8.0/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257670+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.257670+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/thin:23:in `<top (required)>'
2020-12-28T11:11:26.259446+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-12-28 11:11:25 +0000 Using rack adapter
2020-12-28T11:11:26.325893+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-12-28T11:11:26.383463+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

It's complaining about `config.ru`. This is it:

```
require_relative './config/environment.rb'
use EntreeController
use UserController
run ApplicationController
```

I am not using backports in my gemfile, no clue where that error comes from and the error on uninitialized constant is also not clear to me.

No clue where to start looking for the error.

Comment: Your error is not `config.ru` but rather `NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionSpecification` You may need to add `gem 'activerecord', '< 6.1.0'` as it appears this class was removed in `6.1.0` in favor of what appears to be `PoolConfig` and `PoolConfigManager`. Seems there is an [open ticket](https://github.com/sinatra-activerecord/sinatra-activerecord/issues/107) so feel free to contribute there

Comment: Thanks. And that is one point of the problem.